# Why does electrostatic potential inside a conducting spherical shell seem to violate superposition principle?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, conductors

I want to find the potential at the centre of a conducting spherical shell;

The conducting shell bears a total charge of $Q$. The shell has a radius $R$, and there is a point charge of magnitude $q$ outside the shell.

[image]

The potential at the centre is easily arrived at using superposition.

The potential is $$V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \left(\frac{Q}{R} +\frac{q}{x}\right)$$

Now, if I want to calculate the potential at a point inside the shell that is not the centre ( and is at a distance $y$ from the point charge $q$),

[image]

I should get the same value for the answer because potential inside a conducting shell remains constant.

But if that is so, why can't I work backwards? Why can't I write 
$$V_{Y} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \left(\frac{Q}{R} +\frac{q}{y}\right)$$ and then write the same value for the centre? Why does superposition principle seem to not work in this case?

Comment: The charge on the sphere does not have spherical symmetry. You cannot calculate the potential by that formula.

Comment: @nasu why shouldn't it have spherical symmetry?

Comment: Because is a conducting sphere. The charge density will be higher on the side closer to the point charge.

Comment: @nasu even if it doesn't have spherical symmetry, the potential won't change because it only depends on the distance of the charges from the point

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily shown using Gauss's Law that a *uniformly charged* conducting spherical shell has constant potential throughout its interior. This is because the uniform charge distribution gives the situation spherical symmetry, which is used to constrain the behavior of the electric field on a spherical Gaussian surface. However, if the conducting sphere is **not** uniformly charged, then this spherical symmetry is not present, Gauss's Law cannot be usefully applied, and the potential due to an isolated *non-uniformly-charged* conducting spherical shell is **not** constant throughout its interior.

Of course, this situation never happens for an isolated conductor in electrostatics; in the absence of any external influence, the charges on the surface of a conductor will distribute themselves uniformly over the surface. But in your situation, the conductor is not isolated; there's a point charge sitting some distance away from it. Since charges are allowed to move inside the conductor, the charge on the shell will redistribute to a *non-uniform* distribution (for example, if both $Q$ and $q$ are positive, there will be an overdensity of positive charge on the side of the sphere opposite to $q$, and a relatively lower positive charge density on the side of the sphere facing $q$).

So, in your situation, we have two components to superimpose:

- A point charge, with potential $V=\frac{kq}{r}$, and
- A non-uniformly-charged conducting spherical shell, with a complicated potential.

Now, if you superimpose the complicated potential of the non-uniformly-charged spherical shell and the potential of the point charge, you will get a constant potential within the conducting spherical shell. But that is the **result** of the superposition, not an ingredient to it. By starting with a point charge and a constant potential, you're effectively superimposing the point charge twice.

Comment: But what exactly is the result of the superposition? I know that in electrostatics and in questions like this, we are supposed to assume static conditions where the conductor has suitably redistributed its charge distribution to yield zero electric field (therefore constant potential) inside it.

Comment: Once we are inside the spherical shell, its charge distribution will mimic exactly the field of the point charge, only with an opposite sign. Is it impossible to suitably calculate potential using symmetry and theoretical operations?

Comment: If I think it this way: I place a test charge at a distance $x$ from the point charge $q$ and then start building a spherical conducting shell of a radius $R$ around it,  just as depicted. The shell would be supposedly made by introducing infinitesimal charges to it (the way we proceed to calculate its self energy). Will the test charge inside move in the process?

Comment: @AabeshGhosh Well, this problem doesn't really have any useful symmetry (it has rotational symmetry about the line joining the point charge and the center of the sphere, but we're already using that symmetry to transform this 3D situation into a 2D one, only looking at the cross-section of the sphere). I'm not sure what you mean by "only theoretical operations" - what, specifically, does this restrict us to using?

Comment: @AabeshGhosh As for your situation with the test charge, if you place it some distance from the point charge, it will immediately begin to move under the influence of the field from the point charge. I don't think this scenario is particularly informative. Also, I'm not sure it's possible to build a spherical conducting shell by adding charges. A conductor is more than just a charge distribution; a conductor can change from being uncharged to having a non-uniform (and non-zero) charge distribution on its surface in response to an external electric field, after all.

Comment: Okay,so is it really the value I wrote, or is it that the value cannot be deduced only from symmetry principles

Comment: why will potential be non constant inside a conducting shell?

Answer (score 0):

If that really is a conducting shell, then the electric field on the inside must be zero by Gauss' law.

The external charge will have to be developed on the walls of the shell to make the net field zero.

So, essentially, the electric potential on the inside of the shell, as you would know from a bit of integration (considering $E(r)$, where $r$ is the distance between the charge from outside to the origin situated at the center of the sphere) that the potential anywhere on the inside will be equivalent to that on the surface of the conducting shell : i.e. $$V=k\left(\frac{Q}{R} +\frac{q}{r}\right)$$

Comment: Well, the shell won't have uniform charge distribution because of the neighbouring charge, so how is the potential on the surface the value you wrote?

Comment: I did not assume the charge distribution to change on the sphere. I just calculated the net potential at that point.